# PHPWORD is not working on hostinger but on localhost it is working

Tags: php, phpword

```
   include "autoload.php";
   use \PHPOffice\Phpword\Phpword;

   $phpword = new PhpWord();
```

this is giving error on hostinger

> unable to handle request, the page is not loading.

autoload.php file is:

```
<?php
function loadlibraries($class){
    $path=__DIR__."/lib/";
    require_once $path.$class.".php";
}
spl_autoload_register("loadlibraries");
?>
```

Comment: Take a look at [the PHP error logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php-5-apache-fastcgi-and-cpanel), it might contain more detailed error reports.

Comment: First of all, remove the PHP closing tag. Second, make sure the lib directory is in the same directory as the autoload.php.

Comment: It is working on localhost but not on hostinger

Comment: You already wrote that in your title. Did you find any errors?

Comment: No, there is no error but still it is not working